# Comparing the inequalities of Azuma and Chernoff

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $p = p(n) \in (0, 1)$. Let $X$ be the
> sum of the i.i.d. random variables $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$, which are $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$
> with probability $1-p$. Define a martingale $X_0,\ldots, X_n$ that satisfies $X_0 = \mathbb{E}[X]$ and $X_n = X$. Compare the bound resulting from Azuma's inequality
>
> $$\mathbb{P}[X > \mathbb{E}[X] + t]$$
>
> with the bounds that our two versions of Chernoff's inequality give us. Which one is better? Does the answer depend on the choice of $p(n)$ and $t$?

I will write out the inequalities as we did them in the lecture:

> **Azuma:** Let $(X_0, \ldots, X_n)$ be a martingale with $X_0 = 0$ and $\lvert X_i - X_{i-1} \rvert \le 1 \quad (\forall 1 \le i \le n)$. Then for any $t > 0$ it holds
>
> $$\mathbb{P}[X_n \ge \mathbb{E}[X]+t] \le \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{2n} \bigg)$$
>
> **Chernoff 1:** Let $X \sim Bin(n,p)$. Then for any $t > 0$ it holds
>
> $$\mathbb{P}[X \ge \mathbb{E}[X]+t] \le \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{2(\mathbb{E}[X]+t/3} \bigg) = \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{2(np+t/3)} \bigg)$$
>
> **Chernoff 2:** Let $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ with $\sigma^2 := \mathbb{V}[X]$. Then for any $t > 0$ it holds
>
> $$\mathbb{P}[X \ge \mathbb{E}[X]+t] \le \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{2(\sigma^2+t/3} \bigg) = \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{2(p(1-p)+t/3)} \bigg)$$

So we need to compare the terms $2n, 2(np+t/3)$ and  $2(p(1-p)+t/3)$.  Since $n \ge 1$ it is clear that

$$2(np+t/3) \ge 2(p(1-p)+t/3).$$

On the other hand I can see that for $p(n) \rightarrow 1$ and , $6n(1-p) \le t$, which I obtained by reordering $2n \le 2np +t/3$, we have

$$2(np+t/3) \ge 2n$$

Similarly I got that for either $6n(1-p) \ge t$ or $p(n) \rightarrow 0$ together with $t \le 3n$  we have

$$2(np+t/3) \le 2n.$$

However, I am wondering if a more sophisticated comparsion is possible.